# Exact sign of determinant in Java

Tags: math

Is there some Java math library for computation of exact sign of determinant?
This library have to support exact computation with constructive zero bounds, precision-driven approach and numerical filters for performance.

For example: When I simply use Java BigDecimal number type for computation, zero problem occurs. If result is, for example, 1.0E-101, is it zero? yes or no? Solution based on constant zero bound (like 0.0E-100) is inexact and not robust, in my opinion.

Thank you for response.

**Note:**
Personally, I tried  libraries JScience, Common Math, but I have not proof that this libraries use exact computation.

JScience offers [Rational](http://jscience.org/api), but there is problem with operation inverse (0/x failed). Also JScience offers Real, but there is problem with inverse too (Exactness is lost).

It seems that Common Math use BigDecimal in inexact mode. (see [BigReal](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.2)). May be BigFraction is exact, but I have not proof.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use [BigDecimal.signum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#signum%28%29) to test the sign of a BigDecimal.

Comment: I think, this works fine if number is exactly zero. For example 0.0E-100. However, some algorithms, like LU decomposition, can return zero as 12345E-100 (so 0.00000.....12345). Method signum return 1 in this case, but right response is zero. This is where the zero bounds become essential, I think.